# Creating interlocking geometry

Tags: modeling, scatter-objects-addon

How can one create interlocking geometry from scattered spheres, mesh circles, or other meshes? Below are spheres scattered on a chameleon which are then made into scales, all done using a proprietary tool in Maya.

[image: Chameleon1]

[image: Chameleon2]

Comment: I believe the operation you’re looking for is a Boolean operation. Notably, the proprietary tool seems like it’s little more than a well configured particle system to me.

Comment: TheLabCat What kind of Boolean operation do I need to use?

Comment: Union, but how to do it exactly depends a bit on wether the spheres are in the same mesh, are particles, or are individual objects.

Comment: The spheres were distributed on a mesh using a particle system and I could distribute spheres in Blender using the Ditribute Points on Faces node.